# How to increase line spacing in GNOME Terminal on CentOS 7 to increase readability

Tags: terminal, centos-7, gnome-terminal

I am using CentOS 7 in Virtualbox on mac and I am amazed to see that there is no option of increasing line spacing in GNOME Terminal to increase readability. I can do it easily on mac but cant do it on CentOS 7. Any idea how can I do it or any alternative? There is option to increase font size and style but no line spacing.

I am happy to install any alternative terminal with the line spacing feature.

Comment: You should [edit] the question to mention which terminal emulator is being used. I've only ever installed CentOS without a GUI so don't know what the default terminal emulator is. As an alternative, if you configure SSH on the CentOS guest, you could use your own terminal emulator running natively on the Mac.

Comment: Default is gnome-terminal. Doing ssh from guest OS is a reasonable solution, however what if I am working directly on the server? I am happy to install any alternative terminal with the line spacing feature.

Comment: I've edited your question for you to make it more answerable.  I'd also suggest taking a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/194264/how-do-i-change-the-line-spacing-in-terminal

Answer (score 1):

This feature was just recently added to the latest stable version (as we speak) of this terminal emulator, namely GNOME Terminal 3.28 and underlying VTE (Red Hat / Fedora / CentOS package name: vte291) version 0.52.

You might try to install these packages from Fedora 28, I'd guess it most likely works, but I cannot guarantee it. Or you can download, compile and install the newest VTE followed by GNOME Terminal.

xterm, urxvt, konsole are some other possible choices that offer line spacing.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a link for downloading the tar of GNOME Terminal 3.28?

Comment: Any search engine should answer you this in a couple of seconds. I'm terribly sorry but I won't be able to provide step by step help. Thanks for your understanding!